General architecture for React calling AWS and SQS
Kinda new to AWS. I have this high-level question. I’m looking for some insights about the general architecture and workflow, without the need to get into details.
So: I need a React app on the client, which is called AWS. In turn, on the server, some code will send a queue message to some third party to perform some action. While waiting for a response, the react app will show status updates, meaning the different stages of the operation taking place on the server. When all is done, it’ll show a response.
So that’s how I’d build it: React calls API gateway, which in turn calls a Lamba function, which then calls SQS and sends a message on some queue. But what I am not sure about is:

How would the Lambda wait for the response? Is it a 2-way queue, is Lambda keep polling it until there’s an answer and then return it to the client, or would there be two Lambdas? One that sends a queue and the other triggered by a response…? And if it’s a second Lambda, how would the React query it? Would there be some sort of Id when sending, and the third party returns a queue message when it's done with that Id that we can match them, or…? What would trigger that 2nd Lamba (if we’re doing two lambdas) a message arriving in queue would be the trigger, or would it keep polling, or…?
How would the React client update the message? Keep polling some API? A different API than the one sent? Would I need websockets to show status updates, or something like RXJS or…? Would it be all about querying some API over HTTP (with Axios or Fetch API or whatever) or would it be some NPM package that queries a queue, in which case I might not even need Lambda checking for a return message, like Amplify from aws-amplify..?

Would appreciate any sort of knowledge answer. Again, just the high-level architecture\flow details. The rest I’ll figure out on my own.
Thanks!

You send a request, you get a response. In order to send a response you need to keep the request that reached lambda "open" (=lambda is running, i.e. polling some results). Which I cannot recommend.

Lambda is charged per miliseconds running. If it waits until something is resolved, you will be paying for it as long as it open. Therefore it will be super-expensive compare to other solutions.

If you want to have it like this (=client send request, it will be open for i.e. few seconds until everything you want is resolved, then you send response) use Fargate. (you have to provide docker image, not just code, but then it is basically also serverless, you dont have to care about anything). Single container can usually handle hundreds of concurrent requests.
With container you can also use Websockets, which essentially do what you want (you dont have to do long polling/status polling, you can update client proactively from backend through the websocket).
The most simple solution using serverless would be probably with 3+ lambdas:

Start the flow (=sending something to the Queue)
(1 or more lambdas) Process whatever you need, I dont know triggers if 3rd party sends you webhook or you are connected to that 3rd party queue and they let you know something is finished. Or some lambda that is triggered through CRON each x-seconds.
Status of the flow (=this will be called periodically by React client after creating the flow)


Thank you very much for your detailed response!
So its not recommended to keep the lambda open and polling, because I’ll be charged for it. That’s important. But how would Fargate make a difference? The Lambda code will still be polling and so running…
In any event, Your simple solution , you suggest sending something to the queue and the Lambda ends. Another Lambda to be triggered by a returning SQS message? And this will update DynamoDB or some other repository, while React querying periodically some API which in turns returns the status from that repository? Did I get all that right?

Fargate solution - it means that instead of using Lambdas, you would use Fargate (=no lambdas).  One fargate container with 1cpu + 2GB RAM costs about 0.055$/hour which is about 40$/month. For example one Node.js container with 1 CPU can handle up to thousands of concurrent requests per second (depending of course on what you do with that requests). If you have on average 100 requests per second (something that should be easily managed by single container) and it takes 3 seconds to finish, Lambda would cost about 6500$/month.

The other part - yes I believe that you get it right.
